# jQuery: UL select parent li who have children only

Tags: jquery, css, list, jquery-selectors

This has been boggling my mind all afternoon, how do I get my jQuery statement below to only select parent `<li>` who have children?

To put it simply, I need to add a css class to `<li>` items 6, 4 & 8 because they have children directly below them. My statement goes too deep, it adds the redColor class to li's 7, 10, 9, 11, 12..

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#test-list li:has(ul)").addClass("redColor");
 });
```

---

```
<ul id="test-list">
 <li id="listItem_1"> <strong>Item 1</strong> </li>
 <li id="listItem_2"> <strong>Item 2</strong> </li>
 <li id="listItem_3"> <strong>Item 3</strong> </li>
 <li id="listItem_5"> <strong>Item 5</strong> </li>
 <li id="listItem_6"> <strong>Item 6</strong>
    <ul>
        <li id="listItem_4"> <strong>Item 4</strong>
            <ul>
                <li id="listItem_7"> <strong>Item 7</strong> </li>
                <li id="listItem_10"> <strong>Item 10</strong> </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
 </li>
 <li id="listItem_8"> <strong>Item 8</strong>
    <ul>
        <li id="listItem_9"> <strong>Item 9</strong> </li>
        <li id="listItem_11"> <strong>Item 11</strong> </li>
        <li id="listItem_12"> <strong>Item 12</strong> </li>
    </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

View on jfiddle as well: http://jsfiddle.net/t6a6G/9/

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look closely, you'll see that your jQuery selector is actually working correctly, and only li's 6, 4, and 8 have the class you're adding.

The reason the other li's are turning red is that the default color is `inherit`, the same color as your parent.  So setting an li to have `color: red` also makes its descendants red, unless there's another style that applies to them.

Adding a style like `li { color: black; }` will make it more obvious that your class is indeed only applied to the correct list items.

Answer (score 1):

Your selector is just fine. It's adding the `redColor` class correctly, but the children inherit the color of their parents, so they turn red as well.

You should override this behaviour by explicitly setting the color of `<li>`s that don't have the `redColor` class:

```
li {
    color:black;
}
```

See ammended fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/t6a6G/12/.

Comment: Thanks Box9, I just read John's same answer - kind of a duh moment for me! I should have looked at the generated source in my web dev plugin!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting spaces between two things in the CSS, use a ">". So "A > B" means that B is directly a child of A. Also, you were adding the redColor class to everything in the li, and that also includes the ul inside the li. I think you just wanted the strong tags to be red.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// Trying to add css class to li who are parents of children
// When working correctly only items 6, 4, and 8 would be red
    $("#test-list > li:has(ul) > strong").addClass("redColor");
});
```

Comment: Ignore the strong tags, I removed a lot of code from the example to post it - I need the redColor class to be applied to the li. Thanks for the suggestion though!